# Сохранение значений поиска в Select2 инпутах

Tags: jquery, ajax, select2

Как сохранять значения поиска в Select2?

```
<div class="search_article">
  <span>Артикул</span>
  <select name="article[]" id="article" multiple="multiple"></select>
</div>
```

Подключаю к селектам плагин Select2 и произвожу поиск по нажатию кнопки "Искать", соответственно страница перезагружается производится поиск через GET. Какие настройки нужны чтобы значения поиска сохранялось в инпуте?
Ну или 2 выход как сделать AJAX поиск по нажатию кнопки "Искать".

$_GET запрос:

```
http://test2.jewfoto.ru/search?article_type%5B%5D=%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84
```

имена которые ввожу в input

JS код подключение селекта:

```
$(".search_article select").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: "/index.php/search/jsonTags?type=1",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                query: params.term,
                page: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            var items =  $.map(data, function(item, i, params) {
                    return {
                        text: item.tag,
                        slug: item.tag,
                        id: item.tag
                    };
                });

            return {results: items};
        }
    },
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: "Введите ариткул",
    language: "ru",
    templateResult: function (data) {
        if (data.id === '') { // adjust for custom placeholder values
            return 'Custom styled placeholder text';
        }

        var term = $('.select2-search__field').val();
        var $text = $('<span>'+data.text.replace(term, '<strong>'+term+'</strong>')+'</span>');
        return $text;
    }
});
```

Comment: дак у тебя отправляется `$_GET`, запиши его в поле селекта, в чем проблема? :)

Comment: Как записать? добавить внутри select - а option или что?)

Comment: в каком виде у тебя в $_GET значения лежат, добавь в вопрос

Comment: как вариант на клиенте сохранять выбранные значение, и их восстанавливать. либо как Вы сами заметили `ajax` который выполняет необходимые действия на сервере а на клиенте *рендерится* результат

Comment: @pwnz22 после загрузки можешь присвоить значение $('#article').select2('val', 'мое значение')

Comment: @Bald Как бы это сделать ?? в JS я совсем новичок. Плагин это еле-еле встроил) и то тут помогли)

Comment: я могу только Вам описать как бы я это сделал, на [tag:php] я не сильный помощник. что Ваш метод возвращает? `html` разметку? если да то Вам необходимо подключить `ajax` в ваше приложение и при клике по кнопе выполнить `ajax` запрос, а его результат вывести на исходную страницу.

Comment: Использую AJAX для получения данных в JSON. Как бы этим всем занимается данный плагин. Я просто передаю нужные значения по поиску. Поправил вопрос.